# How do I invoke an @IBAction on an NSViewController wrapped in NSViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swiftui

How do I invoke an `@IBAction` on an `NSViewController` subclass wrapped in `NSViewControllerRepresentable`?

Comment: IBAction is for actions triggered by a Storyboard component. It doesn’t make much sense to have that in SwiftUI.

Comment: @jnpdx It does when you've wrapped a view controller in a SwiftUI view hierarchy.

Comment: You have to instantiate the storyboard in the NSViewControllerRepresentable without a storyboard there is no hi to trigger the action.

Answer (score 0):

One proposed solution I found worked in this case (where it was enough to send the action through the `NSResponder` chain). I’d still be curious to know how to target a specific `NSResponder` (for example, if I want to send a command to my embedded view controller from the toolbar).

```swift
(in my Swift app commands):
    CommandMenu("View") {
        Button {
            NSApp.sendAction(#selector(AppCommands.zoomIn), to: nil, from: nil)
        } label: {
            Label("Zoom In", systemImage: "plus")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("+", modifiers: [.command])
```

```swift
@objc
protocol
AppCommands
{
    func zoomIn(_ : Any?)
    func zoomOut(_ : Any?)
}
```